# How can I keep the position of keys when I rename the name of key in ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, xml, hash

I want to covert json to xml.
At first, I converted json to hash because I want to change the name of some keys. I used mappings for the change.

```
@issue_xml = "tmp.xml"

issues = File.new(@issue_xml, File::WRONLY|File::TRUNC|File::CREAT)

issues.puts "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"

issues.puts "<errorList xmlns=\"http://www.klocwork.com/inForce/report/1.0\" version=\"9.5.2\">"
mappings = {"id" => "problemID","severityCode" => "severitylevel","status" => "citingStatus"}

my_hash = JSON.parse(line)    
my_hash.keys.each { |k| my_hash[ mappings[k] ] = my_hash.delete(k) if mappings[k] }


my_xml = my_hash.to_xml(:root => 'problem')

my_xml.each_line do |line|        
    next if line.start_with?("<?xml") or line.eql?("<hash>") or line.eql?("</hash>")
    issues.puts line        
end 
issues.puts "</errorList>"

issues.close
```

With the code above, I can generate a xml file.
But the result is a little different from that I expect.

Here is my question.

I hope that key 'problemID' appear in the beginning of the each problem. but newly mapped keys 'problemID, severityCode, citingStatus' are moved to the end.

Could you let me know how I can keep the positions of the keys?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
issues = File.new(@issue_xml, File::WRONLY|File::TRUNC|File::CREAT)
```

is equivalent to:

```
issues = File.new(@issue_xml, 'w')
```

...so unless you like typing all those constants OR'ed together, use the shorter version.

Next, most likely in your lifetime you will never need to escape a quote in ruby.  This:

```
issues.puts "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"
```

is equivalent to:

```
issues.puts %Q{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>}
```

and in this case, you could just write:

```
issues.puts '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'
```

Where is the line variable:

```
my_hash = JSON.parse(line)
```

Hashes don't have a to_xml() method:

```
my_xml = my_hash.to_xml(:root => 'problem')
```

I'm not sure why you posted all that code that doesn't run...because your question has nothing to do with that code.  Try this:

```
data = {
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'c' => 3,
}

key_map = {
  'b' => 'y',
  'a' => 'x',
}

results = {}

data.keys.each do |key|
  new_key = key_map[key] || key
  results[new_key] = data[key]
end

p results

--output:--
{"x"=>1, "y"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

Comment: I resolved it by using your recommendation. And I installed active_support to use 'to_xml'. So, my script is running. Thanks alot @7stud

Answer (score 0):

This code would appear to be putting things in the order of the unmapped JSON rather than the order of the 'mappings' hash.

You could try something like this?

```
mappings = {"id" => "problemID","severityCode" => "severitylevel","status" => "citingStatus"}

hash = JSON.parse(line)    
my_hash = {}
mappings.keys.each { |k| my_hash[ mappings[k] ] = hash.delete(k) if hash[k] }
my_hash.merge! hash
```

Comment: I tried it. the results shows that all mapped keys are moved to the beginning of the xml @A Fader Darkly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if I understand the question. Please let me know if the following satisfies your requirements. If it does not, please change my example as needed and provide the desired result for `my_hash`.

**Code**

```
my_hash = JSON.parse(line)
mappings.each { |k,_| my_hash[mappings[k] = my_hash.delete(k) }
```

**Example**

```
mappings = { "id"=>"problemID", "severityCode"=>"severitylevel",
             "status"=>"citingStatus" }
my_hash = { "cat"=>0, "id"=>1, "status"=>2, "severityCode"=>3,
            "problemID"=>4, "dog"=>5, "citingStatus"=>6, "severitylevel"=>7 }
mappings.each { |k,_| my_hash[mappings[k]] = my_hash.delete(k) }
my_hash
  #=> { "cat"=>0, "problemID"=>1, "dog"=>5,
  #     "citingStatus"=>2, "severitylevel"=>3 }
```